# How to create Date() from timestamp by server time?

Tags: javascript, php, timestamp, mobiscroll

My web app is currently hosted somewhere in Great Britain and i have 2 hour difference with it but i need to use the time that is used by the server. So i use `time() * 1000` and create from this `timestamp` new date object like `time_data.minDate = new Date(<?php echo $test_time['start'];?>);`, but i still receive +2h.

Full example:

```
time_data.minDate = new Date(<?php echo $test_time['start'];?>);
time_data.maxDate = new Date(<?php echo $test_time['end']['min'];?>);

console.log(time_data.minDate);
console.log('<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $test_time['start'] / 1000)?>');
console.log(time_data.maxDate);
console.log('<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $test_time['end']['min'] / 1000)?>');
```

[image]

So is it possible somehow to force to use the date from timestamp?

Answer (score -1):

Set different time zone for your PHP server:

```
date_default_timezone_set ('Europe / Rome');
```

More information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: i dont need to set it. I just need to create the date from timestamp as it is.

Comment: OK for create the date from timestamp use this function [strftime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Comment: i think you didn't understand my question: the main problem is that js adds timezone to the date and i don't need it. Everything else is fine.